# Error in Android projects (in Eclipse) without a reason

Tags: android

I have a problem with the Android projects in Eclipse.

I am working on Mac OS Lion and when I went to continue an Android project it gives me an error on the project icon. Moreover when I went to see the error Eclipse does not gives me an error anywhere in code.

What can I do to solve this problem? Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

---

After a lot of work I have this problem now:

Eclipse it gives me error on override methods of class preference activity. for example for the code below:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());

            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Show something if does not exit the app
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

I get the error: *The method onPreferenceClick(Preference) of type new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){} must override a superclass method*

This problem is only on Mac OS X Lion. I don't know where is the problem. All tools are installed.

On windows is just fine on the other hand.

Do you have any idea where is the problem now ?

Comment: Along the bottom there's a series of tabs:  "Problems", "javadoc", "Console", etc.  Click "Problems".

Comment: Please, do not paste follow up commentary or additional information as answers. See the [faq]. Answers are reserved for answers that directly answer your question, so they can be voted on. Edit your question to provide additional detail, use comments under your question and answers others give for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The common reason is a error in project. Recheck references for all jars and path to android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

1. Try doing a `Project --> Clean` and see if that helps. Restart Eclipse too.
2. Ensure that you have installed all of the necessary SDKs/APIs in the Android SDK Manager. Perhaps the reason it works on your Windows machine but not your Mac is because your Mac does not have the necessary SDKs installed to ensure that your application compiles/builds.

Also, please post the errors that Eclipse is giving you... if you want others to help you solve the problem, I suggest you improve the quality of your question :).